# Recursive type class for OfNat Even

Tags: lean4, beginner, errors

I'm working my way through [Functional Programming in Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/functional_programming_in_lean/type-classes/polymorphism.html). There's an exercise to create an `Even` class to represent even natural numbers.

I was able to define addition, multiplication, and `toNat`, but defining using recursive instance search to define `OfNat` for `Even` has me stumped. Here's my basic scaffolding for `Even`:

```
inductive Even : Type where
  | zero
  | succ : Even → Even

def Even.toNat : Even → Nat
  | Even.zero => 0
  | Even.succ n => 2 + n.toNat

instance : ToString Even where
  toString n := toString n.toNat
```

For `OfNat`, I have the base case figured out:

```
instance : OfNat Even 0 where
  ofNat := Even.zero

def zeroEven : Even := 0
```

The book says I need `Nat.zero`, but `0` worked just fine.

My code for the recursive case does not compile; it's my best guess so far, but the book has not taught `inferInstance` yet, so there's probably a simpler solution that doesn't use it:

```
instance : OfNat Even (n + 2) where
  ofNat := Even.succ (inferInstance : OfNat Even n).ofNat
```

The error message is on `inferInstance` and says `failed to synthesize instance OfNat Even n`. I believe the basic idea is right, though; I need to synthesize an `Even` for `n+2` by taking the successor of a synthesized `Even` for `n`, and so on with `0` as the base case.

What am I doing wrong? How do I synthesize `Even` via recursive instance search?

Comment: Can you supply the section number and exercise number?

Comment: Without knowing more about the exercise, I can only guess what the author meant, but I’m pretty sure he didn’t mean to create a natural number-like inductive type which is isomorphic to the evens, where you need those conversion functions. Did the book really say “class” or did it say “type”.  If “class”, then use `class` to define `Even`, i.e. `class Even (n : Nat) with …`.  If “type”, then I assume he wants a Prop type `Even : Nat -> Prop`.

Comment: Ignore my above comment.  I misunderstood the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close!  In order to show `n+2` is even, you first have to assume `n` is even.  You do this by adding the instance implicit argument `[OfNat Even n]` to the second instance:

```
instance : OfNat Even 0 where
  ofNat := Even.zero

instance [OfNat Even n] : OfNat Even (n + 2) where
  ofNat := Even.succ (inferInstance : OfNat Even n).ofNat
```

What instance search does when it encounters, say, `OfNat Even 8` is that it first checks if `8` is `0`, which is is not, since that would match the first instance.  Otherwise, based on the second instance it checks if `8` can be syntactically manipulated into the form `n + 2` for some `n` (in this case `6`).  If so, then it repeats that process for `n` until it reaches the base case of `0` or it gives up. That why these work:

```
#check (0 : Even)
#check (2 : Even)
#check (4 : Even)
#check (250 : Even)
```

but these fail:

```
#check (1000 : Even)
#check (0+0 : Even)
```

---

Edit:  I used `inferInstance` just to copy your current approach, but like you said, it is not ideal.  To understand what to use in place, it is important to understand how type class inference works.  By adding the instance implicit argument `[OfNat Even n]` to the arguments of the instance, we make our instance of `OfNat Even n` available to any function in the body of our `instance` which also takes in an implicit instance argument of form `[OfNat Even n]`.

The most general such function is `inferInstance` which has type:

```
#check inferInstance
--  inferInstance.{u} {α : Sort u} [i : α] : α
```

so it can take in an available instance for any type `α` including `OfNat Even n`.

But in your case all you want to do is access the field `ofNat` of your instance `inst : OfNat Even n`.  There are two ways to do this.

First, you can just reference `inst` by name as in

```
instance [inst : OfNat Even n] : OfNat Even (n + 2) where
  ofNat := Even.succ (inst.ofNat)
```

Second, the fields of a class like `OfNat` are themselves functions which take instance implicit arguments.

```
#check OfNat.ofNat
--  OfNat.ofNat.{u} {α : Type u} (x✝ : Nat) [self : OfNat α x✝] : α
```

(Note Lean only makes you directly supply the `x : Nat` and not `α : Type u` since the latter is inferred by the output type.  So you can call `OfNat.ofNat n` to indirectly access the available instance of `OfNat Even n` as in:

```
instance [OfNat Even n] : OfNat Even (n + 2) where
  ofNat := Even.succ (OfNat.ofNat n)
```

---

Edit: If this exercise was particularly confusing to you, you might want to file an issue in the [book's repo](https://github.com/leanprover/fp-lean).  The author seems very response to user feedback.

---

Edit: Another good resource for type class inference in Lean is the [Type Classes chapter of Theorem Proving in Lean 4](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/type_classes.html).  (Even if you just want to use Lean for programming, this chapter is a great resource.)

Comment: The `[OfNat Even n]` is what I was missing! I'm still not sure if the author meant me to use `inferInstance`, since that wasn't introduced yet, but after doing some research I don't know how else to create an instance.

Comment: @NateGlenn I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the edits! Both of the options you added were really good learning moments for me. And yes, I will probably write at the repository at some point; the treatment of recursive type class resolution was too cursory to get a good understanding of.